# c++/cli Accessing a dataset problem

Tags: database, dataset, c++-cli

I'm having trouble accessing a dataset. I've pulled data from an Access database (successfully I think) but I'm now having trouble accessing the data. I think it's a syntax problem. The errors I'm getting are varied, but the current one is: "error C3867: 'System::Object::ToString': function call missing argument list; use '&System::Object::ToString' to create a pointer to member"

Am I attempting this correctly?

```
ds = gcnew DataSet;      
con = gcnew OleDb::OleDbConnection;
con->ConnectionString = dbProvider + dbSource;
con->Open();
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_Gateway";
da = gcnew OleDb::OleDbDataAdapter(sql,con);
da->Fill(ds, "Gateway");

con->Close();

ds_gw = gcnew DataTable;
ds_gw->TableName = "Gateways";
ds->Tables->Add(ds_gw);
dr = ds_gw->Rows[0];
errBox->AppendText(dr->default["Gateway_UID"]->ToString);
```

Comment: this link my problem i need the stringconnection call method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034409/visual-c-connect-to-accdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
errBox->AppendText(dr->default["Gateway_UID"]->ToString());
```